# Rails BST timezone implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, binary-search-tree

Does anyone know how i can use BST for config.time_zone in my rails config/environment.rb file?

At the moment i have left it as UTC and i'm thinking of adding BST to the list of supported timezones, and then extending the Time class to respect this (> last sunday of X month + 1hr)

Where can i find the list of supported timezones?

Searching around i have found alot of complaints but not alot of answers. this will be up on guthub asap.

Cheers, Dougle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
rake time:zones:all
```

You'll probably see a time zone named *`London`*, which is just `UTC +00:00`, but should handle UK daylight saving time properly.

Comment: Unfortunately 'London' is still coming out an hour early, i guess it's an alias of UTC the same as GMT was

Comment: Wait no, you were right London does use BST, i was looking at the sql queries in the log which are of course UTC only, Cheers molf

Answer (score 2):

The TimeZone you need to set is UK, this will automatically handle BST

```
Time.zone = 'London'
Time.zone.now
 => Sun, 17 Oct 2010 02:09:54 BST +01:00
```

Comment: Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
 :001 > Time.zone = 'UK'
ArgumentError: Invalid Timezone: UK