# Rails - Is there an easy way to check if British Summer Time and GMT are different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been reading [Rails BST timezone implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340037/rails-bst-timezone-implementation) however the method listed doesn't seem to work any more:

```
Time.zone = 'London'
Time.now = 2017-04-10 15:47:45 +0100
Time.zone = 'Cairo'
Time.now = 2017-04-10 15:47:45 +0100
```

This is clearly wrong. Is there an easy way for me to check? My end result is trying to see if the London timezone has +0100 in it or not, could I simply do Time.now.include?('+0100')

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the method listed doesn't seem to work any more

You're using the wrong method:

- [`Time.now`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Time.html#method-c-now) is a Ruby method returning a "plain" `Time` instance.
- [`Time.zone.now`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-now) is a Rails method returning a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance.

There's also a shortcut [`Time.current`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-current):

```
Time.zone = 'London'

Time.zone.now
#=> Mon, 10 Apr 2017 15:54:35 BST +01:00

Time.current
#=> Mon, 10 Apr 2017 15:54:35 BST +01:00
```

With another time zone:

```
Time.zone = 'Cairo'

Time.zone.now
#=> Mon, 10 Apr 2017 16:54:35 EET +02:00
```

> My end result is trying to see if the London timezone has +0100 in it or not

In that case "+0100" indicates [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). The proper method is [`dst?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-dst-3F):

```
t1 = Time.zone.parse('2017-03-26')   #=> Sun, 26 Mar 2017 00:00:00 GMT +00:00
t2 = Time.zone.parse('2017-03-27')   #=> Mon, 27 Mar 2017 00:00:00 BST +01:00

t1.dst?   #=> false
t2.dst?   #=> true
```